# ¿Como creo una tabla de mysql en python?

Tags: python, mysql

estoy queriendo crear una tabla en python para luego después ponerle todos los datos desde mysql. Pero me da error...
AQUI LES COMPARTO MI CODIGO:

```
from sqlalchemy import  create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

conexion = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="123456",
)

CanalDeVenta= pd.read_csv('CanalDeVenta.csv')
CanalDeVenta.to_sql(name='',con='',if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Y AQUI ESTA EL ERROR:

```
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[60], line 2
      1 CanalDeVenta= pd.read_csv('CanalDeVenta.csv')
----> 2 CanalDeVenta.to_sql(name='',con='', if_exists='replace', index=False)

ArgumentError: Could not parse SQLAlchemy URL from string ''
```

Les agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Guau... es un poco lioso tu código...

Creo que el error que estás recibiendo se debe a que estás pasando valores vacíos para los parámetros name y con al intentar crear la tabla en MySQL. Además, es necesario especificar correctamente la conexión a la base de datos y el nombre de la tabla que deseas crear.

Te adjunto un código de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Leer el archivo CSV en un DataFrame
CanalDeVenta = pd.read_csv('CanalDeVenta.csv')

# Conectar a la base de datos MySQL
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:123456@localhost/mydatabase')
# Reemplaza 'mydatabase' con el nombre de tu base de datos MySQL

# Especificar el nombre de la tabla en la base de datos
table_name = 'nombre_de_la_tabla'

# Guardar el DataFrame en la tabla de MySQL
CanalDeVenta.to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
engine.dispose()
```

Supongo que ya lo sabrás, pero tienes que tener instaladas las bibliotecas. Aún así te dejo el pip para poder instalarlas:

```
pip install pandas sqlalchemy pymysql
```

Comment: wow!!! tenias razon habia una cadena vacia en name= tenia que poner el nombre de la tabla... Gracias eres increible.